# Kannel retry when got HTTP error

Tags: http-error, kannel

Kannel does not do any attempts to retry if he got an error requesting get-url or dlr-url. Is there a workaround to make retries?

Answer (score -1):

If it fails to fetch the URL, then the problem is with your web server or the script itself. There is no workaround as far as I know.